# Is $\langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ a finitely presented $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$\langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ is a finitely generated, so the following map is a surjective $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-homomorphsm

\begin{align}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]^2&\to \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle\\
(x,y)&\mapsto 2x+y(1+\sqrt{-5})
\end{align}

And $ker(\varphi)=\{(3a+b(1+\sqrt{-5},-a-2b+a\sqrt{-5}):a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Here, I'd like to show this is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module, but I got stuck and I don't know if this is the correct way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Quick way: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Noetherian ring, so any finitely generated module is finitely presented.  Otherwise: pretty much directly from your calculation, $\ker(\varphi)$ is generated by $(3, -1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1+\sqrt{-5}, -2)$.

Comment: Thanks. The Quick way is great and really useful, I completely forgot $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Noetherian ring, thanks for that. Regarding to the generators, I was making wrong calculations. In some point, I saw those generators but I couldn't show they generate $ker(\varphi)$ as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module. Thank you again, Daniel.

Comment: If you do want to show that $(3, -1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-5}, -2)$ generate the kernel, the way I'd approach that would be via the machinery of Groebner bases...